# Showing ICS feeds

Tags: plugins, import, feed, calendar

We are looking to import a third-party calendar feed into a Craft site.

Are there any plugins or techniques for showing an ICS/iCAL calendar feed within a Craft template?

I've come across this plugin for converting into JSON but not sure how best to bring this into a plugin https://github.com/controlz/CalFileParser

Maybe a good excuse to teach myself plugin development …

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the original calendar data into a JSON or RSS format, then check out the wonderful [Feed Me](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe) plugin. It seamlessly handles JSON, RSS, XML, and ATOM formats.